# Get current machine name apex salesforce

Tags: apex, javascript

Is it possible to get machine name using apex salesforce or any javascript we can use in vf page..

Comment: The name of which machine? The user's?

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to understand and answer if it'd be longer than a single sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser) it looks like this is only possible if the user is using IE, ActiveX is enabled, and whatever other arcane situations `sometimes` applies to.

```
function GetComputerName() {
    try {
        var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
        // Show a pop up if it works
        alert(network.computerName);
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
```